# How can I measure rendering time of huge svg?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom, dom-events

I am trying to figure out how I can measure the rendering time of SVG.
When I make changes to the SVG elements (e.g Zoom In or Zoom Out), it takes a few seconds to take effect because SVG is huge.
And I need to measure the time it took to update for performance analysis purposes.
I have tried several DOM events like `DOMContentLoaded` `DOMNodeInserted` `DOMNodeSubtreeModified` but all these events are triggered before changed SVG is rendered on screen.

I have also tried `PerformanceTimingAPI` and `PerformanceElementTimingAPI` but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "_I have also tried PerformanceTimingAPI and PerformanceElementTimingAPI but no luck._" - show us! Well, really, show us any attempt at solving this yourself. Then we can help you debug it.

Comment: If the svg is so big that any change you make "takes a few seconds to take effect" you may need to think of an alternative solution. You may find [this article by Sara Soueidan](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/optimizing-svg-delivery-with-svg/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

There’s also [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but if you’re already experiencing trouble with JS events saying a change happened in the DOM, but you’re not seeing the browser engine re-render, then you might not be able to use JS to measure this and may need to use a more “manual” method.

Try using Chrome DevTools’ [Performance recording](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/reference/#screenshots) feature. If you enable screenshots, you should be able to see when the rendering took effect. Combine this with [performance.mark()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/mark) and you should be able to see when you triggered the DOM mutation, and when the screenshot actually updated.